# Tensorflow 2.0 custom layer crashes with 31 inputs, but is fine with 33 inputs

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking at a very simple custom layer which outputs a trainable variable, but ignores the input:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs  = tf.random.normal(shape=[500,1])

class MyLayer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        print( "Input shape", input_shape)
        self.kernel = tf.Variable( [-1.0] )

    def call(self, input):
        print( " Call", input.shape )
        return self.kernel

model = MyLayer()
model.predict( inputs[:33] )

model = MyLayer()
model.predict( inputs[:31] )
```

The first model.predict call succeeds and returns a 33 length array. But the second call crashes
with the error message:
ValueError: Mismatch between expected batch size and model output batch size. Output shape = (1,), expected output shape = shape (31,)

Why would the first call succeed, but the second fail?

Incidentally, if I replace "return self.kernel" in the call definition with "return input*0.0 + self.kernel" then everything works as expected, but I think it should be possible to do this without the multiply by zero which seems unnecessary.

I am trying to implement a layer where the output is trainable, but doesn't depend on input.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you always call them consecutively like that? Also, your build method is formatted poorly. Have you checked how many times build gets called?

Comment: It's really strange, 33 seems to be treated as a single input with a single output, but 31 appears to be treated as a batch size of 31, so it should have 31 outputs.

Comment: Apologies for the build formatting (cut and paste error), it is correct in original. In each case build is called once. Whereas the call function is called twice (in each case), and for the second case, it is the second call which crashes.

Comment: I reduced it down to just 1 call. I think the problem lies in the fact you're just returning a single variable instead of a proper output. Eg. Your kernel shape should be (None, 1) instead of a just (1). The fact the behavior changes when you hit 33 is really strange.

Comment: I think if you look at the code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.9.0/tensorflow_probability/python/layers/variable_input.py#L27-L139

Comment: matt, I'm not quite how to create kernel shape of (None,1). I tried self.kernel = tf.Variable( [None,-1.0] ), but that's not what I want. Do you know how to create kernel with that shape? Apologies for basic question, I'm quite new to python and tensorflow. Thanks for the VariableLayer reference. It seems to be almost what I'm looking for, but it doesn't seem to thread along the input examples. By which I mean it seems to produce a single instance of that given shape regardless of the number of input examples.

Comment: Looking at the code I linked you, which should be "correct" it has the same problem your code does. I suspect you've found a bug, at least in the code I linked you. The broadcasting rules shouldn't change for the length of the input vector.  As they say though, it is just a dense layer with all of the weights set to zero, and the bias can vary. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py maybe that offers a better clue?

Comment: Hi matt, Yes, I had trouble working with the VariableLayer you linked to. It didn't work the way I expected. For the moment, I think I will go with the input*0.0 + tf.Variable trick. It seems to sort out the batch broadcasting correctly, even if it is not the most elegant. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've inspected it a bit more, and it appears the issue is the batch size. The default value appears to be 32, so when you pass 32 or less it processes it as 1 batch and the return value has the wrong dimension. If you call `predict( i, batch_size=1)` it works for both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I found to solve this issue such that the batch is handled is to use `tensorflow.map_fn` that way the value is mapped along the batch axis. It could be managed by changing the return statement.

```
return tf.map_fn( lambda x: self.kernel, input, dtype=tensorflow.float32 )
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that works for me. I had tried to see if there might exist some broadcast based solution, but I could not get that to work. But your solution works. Thanks.

Comment: I looked too, but seem to get stuck at modules that don't exist. I tried tracking down the operations for the basic one like tf.add. I also think there should be a better way to do this.